# Name the header from a file

Tags: r, class, vector, type-conversion

this is the script I'm on:

```
data <- read.table(file.choose(), header = FALSE, sep = "")

data.header <- read.table(file.choose(), header = FALSE, sep = "")
data.names <- as.vector(data.header[1,])
names(data) <- data.names
```

Basically, my intention is to make some sort of "generic" algorithm to take a file, which has the header for my other data. The barrier that is stopping me is, converting the data.header to a vector, so then I can attribute the names to my data.

> names(data) <- " vector "

Can anyone give me a tip?

Comment: At a first glance, you wouldn't need `as.vector`, since the return value of `read.table`is an object of class `data.frame` and therefore its first row can become the `names` of some df with the same number of columns. Can you post the output of `dput(data.header[1,])`? And of `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: `data.header <- read.table(file.choose(), header = T, sep = "")`; `names(data)<-names(data.header)`

Comment: @SRivero  You could post this as an answer so that the question would not go un-answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not working becouse your columns in the data.header are probably `factors`. To make your approach works, you can read your `data.header` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
data.header <- read.table(file.choose(), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = "")
```

and then set the column names

```
 names(data)<-as.character(as.vector(data.header[1,]))
```

This may not work if any of your column is numeric.

As I mentioned in the comments, an easier and safer alternative would be to read the header in `data.header`

```
data.header <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = "")
```

and then set up the column names

```
names(data)=names(data.header)
```